# Parsing icon for applications issue

Tags: c++, qt, registry, windows

I want to get applications icon from the registry. The problem is that I'm getting only default application icon. How to get the actual application icon? Thanks.

**Screenshot:**[image]

**Code:**

```
QStringList allLocalMachineX86Keys;
QString displayIcon;
QString iconFile;
QIcon programIcon;
QStringList displayIconSplitted;
QString iconSplittedData;
QFileIconProvider fileIconProvider;
QString displayName;

QSettings registryKeyLocalMachineX86("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall", QSettings::NativeFormat);
allLocalMachineX86Keys = registryKeyLocalMachineX86.allKeys();

for (QString key : allLocalMachineX86Keys) {
    if (!key.isEmpty()) {
        if (key.contains("DisplayIcon")) {
            displayIcon = registryKeyLocalMachineX86.value(key).toString();

            if (displayIcon.contains("\"")) {
                displayIconSplitted = displayIcon.split("\"");
                iconSplittedData = displayIconSplitted.value(displayIconSplitted.length() - 2);
                iconFile = iconSplittedData;
            } else if (displayIcon.contains(",")) {
                displayIconSplitted = displayIcon.split(",");
                iconSplittedData = displayIconSplitted.value(displayIconSplitted.length() - 2);
                iconFile = iconSplittedData;
            } else {
                iconFile = displayIcon;
            }

            if (iconFile.contains(".ico")) {
                programIcon = QIcon(iconFile);
            } else {
                QFileInfo fileInfo(iconFile);
                programIcon = fileIconProvider.icon(fileInfo);
            }
        } else {
            programIcon = QtWin::fromHICON(LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION));
        }

        if (key.contains("DisplayName") && registryKeyLocalMachineX86.value(key).toString() != "") {
            displayName = registryKeyLocalMachineX86.value(key).toString();
            emit appData(programIcon, displayName);
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**
When I have commented these lines of code:

```
// } else {
//     programIcon = QtWin::fromHICON(LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION));
// }
```

the apps icon displays but some are empty or not from the application (image below):

[image]

Anyone know how to fix it? Thanks in advance.