# Get installed apps data issue

Tags: c++, qt, windows, qvector

```
struct AppsData {
    QList<QIcon> icons;
    QStringList name;
    QStringList version;
    QStringList publisher;
    QStringList installLocation;
    QStringList uninstallLocation;
};

void Test::setAppData(QList<QIcon> icons, QStringList names, QStringList versions, QStringList publishers, QStringList installLocations, QStringList uninstallLocations)
{
    AppsData appsData;
    appsData.icons = icons;
    appsData.name = names;
    appsData.version = versions;
    appsData.publisher = publishers;
    appsData.installLocation = installLocations;
    appsData.uninstallLocation = uninstallLocations;

    QVector<AppsData> dataVector;
    dataVector.push_back(appsData);
}
```

I want to display all apps data in appropriate columns.

**Image:**
[image]

Also I have tried to accomplish it without vectors:

```
for (int i = 0; i < uninstallLocations.count(); i++) {
        allApplicationsItem = new QTreeWidgetItem(allApplications);
        allApplicationsItem->setText(0, names.at(i));
        allApplicationsItem->setText(1, versions.at(i));
        allApplicationsItem->setText(2, publishers.at(i));
        allApplicationsItem->setText(3, installLocations.at(i));
        allApplicationsItem->setText(4, uninstallLocations.at(i));
    }
```

but it doesn't work, the application crashes.

Comment: Don't create `vector.count()` `QTreeWidgetItem`s then. Closing as typo.

Comment: @LogicStuff

I have changed the main post. Thanks. If not use `vector.count()` then how to iterate on vector?

Comment: @Cobra91151 Answering your comment question: you could use QVectorIterator (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvectoriterator.html#QVectorIterator). As for the original question, could you specify what `parent` is, and what do you mean by `it returns but not all (only 5)`?

Comment: @lpares12

The main post has been updated. I meant only 5 items from 12.

Comment: @Cobra91151 and do you want to display the vector values in columns or rows?

Comment: @lpares12

I want to display all values in rows. It should be a list.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are using Qt5:

Once you have a `QTreeWidget` and the vector created, you should iterate over its elements, and create a new `QTreeWidgetItem` for each one, so you'd have something like:

```
QTreeWidget *treeWidget = new QTreeWidget(this);
treeWidget->setCoulmnCount(1);

for(int i = 0; i < vector.count(); i++) {
    QTreeWidgetItem *newItem = new QTreeWidgetItem(treeWidget);
    newItem->setText(0, vector.value(i)); // 0 to display it at column 0
}
```

As you can see, first you need to create the `QTreeWidget` and then add each child as a `QTreeWidgetItem` to it.

By the way, you should consider changing the name of the variable `vector` to something more specific.

Comment: But the vector data be in 0 column?
This is just a small test example. However, what I want is to get all apps data from the registry, and write the data to `QTreeWidgetItem` (`QTreeWidget`), so I decided to use `QVector`, because I can't maintain the right data in right column. Can you help me with it?

Comment: I have updated main post. I want to display data like in the image in my main post using vector in all 5 columns. Thanks.

Comment: @Cobra91151 I can't see the image. Modifying the vector won't change the tree display. Instead, you could save all the `newItem` into a `vector` and modify them directly, or you could do `std::map<std::string, QTreeWidgetItem>` and each time you modify the string, apply `QTreeWidgetItem::setText(string)`.

Comment: Link for the image - [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFDRk.png). I want to display the apps data like in the image with vectors or without but in appropriate column.

5 Columns
1 - Name ( + icon)
2 - Version
3 - Publisher
4 - Install Location
5 - Uninstall Location

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44250058/parsing-icon-for-applications-issue

Comment: You should close this question and make another one with the update, since your original question changed a lot in comparison to what you are asking now.

Comment: I have changed the main post to clarify the issue.